# Is it safe to use webview tag in Electron?

Tags: security, webview, electron

In [Electron's `webview` documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag), there is this warning:

> Electron's webview tag is based on Chromium's webview, which
>   is undergoing dramatic architectural changes. This impacts the
>   stability of webviews, including rendering, navigation, and event
>   routing. We currently recommend to not use the webview tag and to
>   consider alternatives, like iframe, Electron's BrowserView, or an
>   architecture that avoids embedded content altogether.

It recommends not to use `webview`, however none of the alternative such as `iframe` or `BrowserView` can fit my use case as well as `webview` does. So I wonder if the warning above recommends not to use `webview` **only** because the API and architecture can change in the future or is there any known security issues with `webview` right now? And in general, what I care the most is: Is it **safe** to use `webview` (in term of security) right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been answered https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18187.

> Webviews run in a separate process and have node integration disabled by default, so there shouldn't be any major reason why they're less secure than the alternatives. You'll definitely want to use the `webPreferences` option to enable sandboxing, disable the remote module, enable context isolation, etc. ([example for BrowserView](https://github.com/minbrowser/min/blob/1d45be37e06ffef2d520a012c6cfd0eb56e86297/js/webviews.js#L167-L174)).
>
> However, there's a fair number of bugs in webviews right now, some recent examples:
>
> [#17890](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/17890)
>
> [#18019](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18019)
>
> [#18177](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/18177)
>
> Most of these aren't present in BrowserView, so you definitely want to use that instead if it's at all possible to do so.